# Mongoose model - TypeError: Account is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to define a model in account.js and export it to my server.js file. When I try to create a new instance of the model, I get this error:

`"TypeError: Account is not a constructor`

It's probably simple mistake but I couldn't figure out why it's not recognizing it as a constructor.

These are my files:

account.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
const accountSchema = new Schema({
    fullname:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    }
}, {
    collection: 'accounts',
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/accountsdb', (error) => {
    if(error) console.log(error);   
    console.log("Database connection successful."); 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Account = require("account");

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());   
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root : __dirname + '/'});
});

app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    const newAccount = new Account(req.body);     //ERROR here
    newAccount.save((err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    });   
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.js`, your import for `Account` is wrong. Import like this instead:

```
const Account = require("./account");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with the way you required `Account`. Without a "/", "./" or "../" prefixed to `account` in `require('account')`, it is trying to import a core module or one of the node_modules (if in main directory).